# AC-mains capable SSR (Solid State Relay) with very low leakage current?

Tags: solid-state-relay, efficiency

Requirements:

- Can switch 230VAC
- Can switch at least 0.5A (i.e. ol' good 100W incandescent lamp)
- Wastes no more than 3mW in off state
- Low-on resistance is always good too

The stated power usage translates to under 15uA of leakage current.

Unfortunately, I was able to find stated leakage current only in low-current (Io.max < 200mA) devices, e.g. [HSF2](http://www.hongfa.com/pro/pdf/HFS2_en.pdf) (10uA), [HSSR-8400](http://www.datasheetcatalog.org/datasheet/hp/HSSR-8400.pdf) (<1uA). Whenever Io.max is stated at ~2A, leakage current is 10+mA. Do higher-current, yet still modest leakage current SSR exist? Alternatively, can someone point to "raw" thyristor/triac with similar specs?

Comment: How about using two in series?

Comment: Depending on your requirements, you could go for an electromechanical relay, which can handle your required ampacity and would have virtually no leakage current. :-)

Comment: @Oli Glaser: I assume you mean in parallel, to double the current rating. Then, can you point to vendor appnote or trusted textbook example which shows that this is generally accepted technique when dealing with mains electricity? Because otherwise common sense says that in such arrangement, if one component fails/disconnects, the remaining one will get current beyond spec, which will for sure lead to its failure either. And with mains electricity, such failure may be loud and dangerous.

Comment: @pfalcon - nope, I do mean in series. You switch both on/off at the same time so whilst off the total effective impedance is higher and leakage current less.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I was able to find [an explanation](http://www.crouzet-ssr.com/english/faq.shtml#p15) why more or less powerful SSR have noticeable leakage current:

> Leakage current comes from the snubber network. The amount of leakage current (typically 10-15 mA) is dependent on the size capacitor used in the snubber network. Crouzet standard SSRs DO NOT include a resistor-capacitor network in most of its relays, which results in a typical leakage current less than 1mA.

Their [GN841340xx](http://www.crouzet-ssr.com/english/products/download/gnssr.pdf) series are rated at 0.1mA(rms) leakage current for example.

Another reference to snubbers in SSRs: http://www.electronics-tutorials.ws/io/io_5.html