# Solid State Relay is giving off voltage even when turned off

Tags: solid-state-relay

I'm currently creating a circuit according to this schematics i made. I have removed some irrelevant parts for simplification sake.

[image: circuit]

The SSR in question is a [861SSR210-DC-1](https://www.mouser.com/ProductDetail/528-861SSR210-DC-1). When 5v is applied between the + and - the SSR is able to open the circuit and able to give power to the load which is just a cellphone charger. The problem though is when I turn off the SSR it is still letting through some power, the phone goes back on and off of charging.

Tests I have done that might help:

- I removed the load and measure the voltage between A1 and A2. ON = 238v and OFF = 99v on AC settings of my multitester.
- Put the both + and - on GND, A1 and A2 read around 99v AC.
- There are 2 holes in our wall outlet :)
- The SSR is atached to an extension cord, and this extension cord has a LED indicator on it, and when the ssr is off it dims a little bit, sometimes it blinks really fast
- The SSR also has a led indicator so when I say on and off, I have checked that the led is also on and off respectively

Comment: Sounds normal. Look up the leakage current in the datasheet for the SSR. Take a look here https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/264268/d-solid-state-relay-minimum-load-current and here https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/38942/ac-mains-capable-ssr-solid-state-relay-with-very-low-leakage-current

Comment: As Winny says, look at the leakage current on page 3 of the datasheet. It says 10mA can get through when OFF. So if you're only drawing a very small load (such as a phone charger), it would make sense that it appears to stay on.

Comment: I see @winny, will this be harmful to devices? How or what add on the circuit to prevent this 10mA from passing through. I would not like my charger going on and off when the extension chord is supposedly "off"

Comment: @Puffafish . How would i stop this from getting through my device? like can i attach a passive load to take this 10 mA ?

Comment: Use a mechanical relay.

Comment: @Toor It is true that is a good suggestion, but is there any way that will still involve using solid state just for the problems sake?

Comment: None I can think of. Or find a different SSR. One with lower current capability (do you really need 10A for a phone charger? That's 2400W, many hundreds of phone chargers) should have less leakage. Won't beat a mechanical relay for leakage though.

Comment: I just found this in box of random stuff/I was thinking of what are the possible applications of this, from its form factor it looks like it supposed to go in breaker box, and got the idea to use it make a controllable outlet. Thus i made this sample project.

Comment: Highly unlikley to be harmful. Mechanical relay or dummy load which will give a low enough voltage at 10 mA to not bother you. Or different SSR with lower leakage.

Comment: It's made to go into an industrial electrical box in a plant to control stuff.

Comment: Take a look at hybrid relays (SSR+mechanical all in one). More expensive but combines the best of both worlds. Sounds like what you need for an industrial enviorment.

Comment: @winny there were 3 in the box would be a shame to let them go :) ,  Can you tell me how to make this dummy load

Comment: A resistor in parallel with the output (LOAD in the schematic). Make sure it's rated for the full peak voltage.

Comment: If you have three and they cost nothing, connecting them in parallel on the control inputs but in series on the primary contacts will cut leakage by at least 1/3 Totally overkill though.

Comment: @Toor I wouldn’t be sure leakage current is linear.

Comment: i would use an outlet splitter and plug a tungsten nightlight in with the charger. should suck up all the leakage.

Comment: @winny I agree. That's why I said "at least 1/3". I would expect it to actually be better than 1/3.

Comment: @Toor, no, I’m more thinking a constant current sink over a range of input voltage for internal biasing.